# jmap -permstat takes long time and hangs

Tags: jvm, out-of-memory

We started seeing 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space'. In order to findout what is held in perm space, tried running

'/usr/j2sdk1.6.0_13/bin/jmap -permstat 20476 -J-mx1280m > /tmp/permstats20476.txt &'

This command is taking long time ..... in between it gave below exception:

finding class loader instances ..252829 intern Strings occupying 30781792 bytes.
Finding object size using Printezis bits and skipping over...
Finding object size using Printezis bits and skipping over...
Finding object size using Printezis bits and skipping over...
Finding object size using Printezis bits and skipping over...

done.
computing per loader stat ..done.
please wait.. computing liveness...................Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.readBytesFromProcess0(Native Method)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.access$1000(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:51)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal$1ReadBytesFromProcessTask.doit(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:558)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal$LinuxDebuggerLocalWorkerThread.run(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:127)

but it is not completing ...

[svcmig2@app430 ~]$ uname -a
Linux app430... 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:39 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

is there any other alternates to jmap ? so that i get the perm stats fast

Answer (score 2):

> is there any other alternates to jmap ? so that i get the perm stats fast

You can make one yourself! This is really easy with the aid of [Serviceability Agent](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/jvm01/full_papers/russell/russell_html/index.html).

Here is an example for your case:

```
import sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.*;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.*;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.*;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool;

public class PermTool extends Tool {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Show PermGen object histogram
        ObjectHistogram histo = new ObjectHistogram();
        VM.getVM().getObjectHeap().iteratePerm(histo);
        histo.print();

        // List all classes in PermGen with their ClassLoaders
        VM.getVM().getObjectHeap().iteratePerm(new DefaultHeapVisitor() {
            @Override
            public boolean doObj(Oop obj) {
                if (obj instanceof InstanceKlass) {
                    obj.printValue();
                    Oop loader = ((InstanceKlass) obj).getClassLoader();
                    if (loader == null) {
                        System.out.println(" -- loaded by Bootstrap ClassLoader");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" -- loaded by ");
                        loader.printValue();
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PermTool().start(args);
    }
}
```

Just compile and run it using the same JDK as your target process.
Make sure `jdk/lib/sa-jdi.jar` is on the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks Apangin. This gives big picture of Perm space in short time.  But it would be nice to analyze, if we can get detailed breakup of ConstMethodKlass,MethodKlass,ConstantPoolKlass,InstanceKlassKlass,ConstantPoolCacheKlass. Not sure if it is possible ?

Comment: @BhaskarNa Yes, it is possible. Replace `ObjectHistogram` with your custom `HeapIterator` and do whatever you want. What whould you like to see in the "detailed breakup"?

Comment: like which class took how much space for ex.,i am interested in what contributed to make ConstMethodClass to become 40m 1:              288821  44468976        * ConstMethodKlass
2:              288821  39291944        * MethodKlass
3:              30791   38145216        * ConstantPoolKlass
4:              30791   33647264        * InstanceKlassKlass
5:              27913   22935072        * ConstantPoolCacheKlass

Comment: @BhaskarNa OK, I edited the answer so that the tool now prints all classes in PermGen. Looks like your application has loaded nearly 30K classes! There is either a ClassLoader leak or you use CMS GC and have not set `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` JVM options.

Comment: </br> Now i do see all the classes that contributes to 30788 InstanceKlass but I don't see similar break up for others like ConstMethodKlass, MethodKlass, etc., Let me check for these types and see if they gets printed...  </br> 1:              288148  44352968        * ConstMethodKlass
2:              288148  39200416        * MethodKlass
3:              30788   38125192        * ConstantPoolKlass
4:              30788   33637208        * InstanceKlassKlass
5:              27956   22936576        * ConstantPoolCacheKlass
6:              15144   8258912 * MethodDataKlass

Comment: Looks like other Klasses ConstMethodKlass, MethodKlass ,ConstantPoolKlass   doesn't expose classloader to fetch the class details. jmap's format is nice (it has counts for each class) but it doesn't scale ... i don't know why oracle doesn't support JMAP

Comment: @BhaskarNa `ConstMethod`, `Method`, `ConstantPool` etc. are particular parts of class metadata. You don't need to print them separately if you already have all classes listed. Other numbers show that 30788 classes contain 288148 methods with the total size of 80 MB, i.e. 9 methods per class with the average size of 290 bytes. The amount of metadata looks sane, so you have to find why there are so many classes loaded.

Comment: oh ok..out of 30k InstanceKlass, i see around 6k+ loaded by DelegatingClassLoader: InstanceKlass for sun/reflect/GeneratedConstructorAccessor1037 -- loaded by Oop for sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader. Is this something usual?

Comment: @BhaskarNa These dynamically generated classes are used by Reflection: `Method.invoke`, `Construction.newInstance` or `Class.newInstance`. There could be so many classes if you call 6K different methods using Reflection, but this is hardly the case. More likely the classes don't get unloaded. Make sure `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` is set if you are using ConcurrentMarkSweep GC.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can set the JVM args: `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to get .hprof file when the oom arise, then use mat to analysis the duplicate loaded classes.
2. I have write a tool class with SA for your question. My JDK version is 1.8.0_151.

Here is source code：

```
import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.*;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.*;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool;

/**
 * @author duqi
 * @createTime 2018/9/1 下午11:55
 **/
public class PermTool extends Tool {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Show PermGen object histogram
        ObjectHistogram histo = new ObjectHistogram();
        VM.getVM().getObjectHeap().iterate(histo);
        histo.print();

        // List all classes in PermGen with their ClassLoaders
        VM.getVM().getObjectHeap().iterate(new DefaultHeapVisitor() {

            @Override
            public boolean doObj(Oop obj) {
                if (obj.getKlass() instanceof InstanceKlass) {
                    obj.printValue();
                    Oop loader = ((InstanceKlass) obj.getKlass()).getClassLoader();
                    if (loader == null) {
                        System.out.println(" -- loaded by Bootstrap ClassLoader");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" -- loaded by ");
                        loader.printValue();
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PermTool().execute(args);
    }
}
```